# Reading Node info using XDocument - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmlnode

So, this might be a really stupid question, but I'm having a hard to finding an answer that actually works.

So I got an xml looking like this.

```
<LocationList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/xml/rest/hafasRestStopsNearby.xsd">
   <StopLocation name="Tesdorpfsvej (Odense Kommune)" x="10400699" y="55388303" id="461769300" distance="205"/>
   <StopLocation name="Tesdorpfsvej / Munkebjergvej (Odense Kommune)" x="10400681" y="55388303" id="461055900" distance="206"/>
   <StopLocation name="Munkebjerg Plads (Odense Kommune)" x="10401589" y="55386873" id="461120400" distance="312"/>
   <StopLocation name="Munkebjergvej (Odense Kommune)" x="10397463" y="55390514" id="461038500" distance="372"/>
   <StopLocation name="Jagtvej (Odense Kommune)" x="10396456" y="55389489" id="461019400" distance="420"/>
   <StopLocation name="Allegade (Odense Kommune)" x="10396618" y="55390721" id="461026900" distance="430"/>
   <StopLocation name="Guldbergsvej (Odense Kommune)" x="10396923" y="55391422" id="461104100" distance="443"/>
   <StopLocation name="Nansensgade (Odense Kommune)" x="10409436" y="55391799" id="461115400" distance="472"/>
   <StopLocation name="Chr. Sonnes Vej (Odense Kommune)" x="10404483" y="55385219" id="461120300" distance="488"/>
   <StopLocation name="Benedikts Plads (Odense Kommune)" x="10398254" y="55392995" id="461115500" distance="491"/>
</LocationList>
```

I only need to retrieve the stoplocation, and then the different info in each of them.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
foreach (var busstop in xdoc.Descendants())
{
     //return the whole node here       
}
```

How can I extract the name, x, y and id, distance value from each stop location? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I extract the name, x, y and id, distance value from each stop location?

Very simply - just cast the attributes:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
foreach (var stop in xdoc.Root.Elements("StopLocation"))
{
     int x = (int) stop.Attribute("x");
     int y = (int) stop.Attribute("y");
     int id = (int) stop.Attribute("id");
     int distance = (int) stop.Attribute("distance");
     // Use the variables here
}
```

If you're actually going to create a new object, you should consider using `Select` instead, to do the whole thing declaratively. For example:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var stops = xdoc.Root
                .Elements("StopLocation")
                .Select(stop => new BusStop(
                           (int) stop.Attribute("x"),
                           (int) stop.Attribute("y"),
                           (int) stop.Attribute("id"),
                           (int) stop.Attribute("distance")))
                .ToList()
```

That's assuming there's a constructor for `BusStop` that takes those values in that order, of course.